# MVC Razor for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code (nested inside a form post) but am continually getting the error that it's missing the closing **}**

```
@for(int i=0;i< itemsCount; i++){
    <input type="hidden" @string.Format("name= item_name_{0} value= {1}",i,items[i].Description) >
    <input type="hidden" @string.Format("name= item_name_{0} value= {1}",i,items[i].UnitPrice.ToString("c"))>
}
```

I've been staring at it long enough...can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think this snippet has a problem. It shows with no errors on my machine. Maybe you have an extra `{` somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 18):

Try put `@:` before your html code like this:

```
 @for(int i=0;i< itemsCount; i++)
 {
    @: html code here
 }
```

Alternatives:
1. wrap your html code with `<text></text>`
2. use `HtmlHelper` to generate the html code

Answer (score 3):

you may note that for writing a code block you can write in two ways

1. For Only a line of Block ,just like you have written in your code and this encloses just the line that contains the preceding @
2. For Code Block using @{... } ,this gives you freedon to use Code without preceding @ except within HTML expressions .for any html/text  you must precede it with @: you want to print as is,otherwise Razor will try to interpret it as code(Since @: defines content as literal for every code expression under @: you must use @ again for code)

In your case you can do as following

```
@{
    for(int i=0; i < itemsCount; i++)
    {
       @:<input type="hidden" @Html.Raw(string.Format("name= item_name_{0} value=  {1}",i,items[i].Description)) />
       @:<input type="hidden" @Html.Raw(@string.Format("name= item_name_{0} value= {1}",i,items[i].UnitPrice.ToString("c"))) />
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to make use of HTML Helpers. Code will be clean as well (your name format for Description and UnitPrice seems to follow the same format; you may want to change it)

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
    {
        @Html.Hidden(string.Concat("ïtem_name_", i), items[i].Description)
        @Html.Hidden(string.Concat("ïtem_name_", i), items[i].UnitPrice.ToString("c"))           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the `Html.Raw` helper

```
@for(int i=0; i < itemsCount; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" @Html.Raw(string.Format("name= item_name_{0} value= {1}",i,items[i].Description)) />
    <input type="hidden" @Html.Raw(@string.Format("name= item_name_{0} value= {1}",i,items[i].UnitPrice.ToString("c"))) />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
    <input type="hidden" name="@("item_name_" + i)" value="@items[i].Description" />
    <input type="hidden" name="@("item_name_" + i)" value="@(items[i].UnitPrice.ToString("c"))" />
}
```

Note the changes / notes in prashanth's another as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose your for loop body between text tag.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx